# Woes Compiling android Application by hand

Tags: java, android, windows, command-line

I am trying to compile my Android application by hand, using some details i found here:

http://geosoft.no/development/android.html

Everything works. I can now compile my own applications without the need of any tools except mine. This means no Gradle and no Android studio. It works flawless, except when I need to compile an application that uses the Google Play library.

What i am trying to do is create a Google Map instance in my layout, as follows:

```
setContentView(R.layout.mymap_layout);
```

The application crashes with this errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(26119): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(26119): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4703)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:306)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at com.Actividad.Brian.actividad.Google_Maps(actividad.java:2377)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at com.Actividad.Brian.actividad$4.run(actividad.java:1063)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
E/AndroidRuntime(26119):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are the command lines that I am using:

```
// CHECKS THE SHA1 FINGERPRINT OF THE KEYSTORE. (NOT USED FOR V2 OF GOOGLE MAPS). 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\keytool.exe
 -list -keystore "c:\users\brian\documents\Compiler\KeyStore\informes.keystore" -storepass ************** -keypass ********** -alias informes 

// COMPILES THE RESOURCES.
C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\aapt.exe
 package -f -m --auto-add-overlay -S c:\users\brian\appdata\local\android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res -S res -J src -M src\AndroidManifest.xml -I "C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar"

// COMPILES THE RESOURCE CLASS.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\javac.exe
 -d android\bin -classpath "C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar";android\obj;"C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar";"C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar"   -target 1.5 -source 1.5 -version -Xlint:none -version -encoding UTF-8 -sourcepath android\src android\src\com\Actividad\Brian\*.java 

//COMPILES THE JAVA CLASS (USER'S CODE).
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\javac.exe
 -d android\bin  -verbose -Xlint -classpath "C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar"";""android\obj;C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar";"C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar" -sourcepath android\src android\src\com\Actividad\Brian\*.java 

// CREATES THE DEX FILE (ANDROID'S EXECUTABLE).
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe
 -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -jar "C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\lib\dx.jar" --dex --output="C:\Users\brian\Documents\Compiler\Temp\android\bin\classes.dex" "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Compiler\Temp\android\bin" "C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar" "C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar" 

// COMPILES THE APK EXECUTABLE. (UNSIGNED)
C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\aapt.exe
 package -f --auto-add-overlay -M "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Compiler\Temp\android\src\AndroidManifest.xml" -S c:\users\brian\appdata\local\android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res -S "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Compiler\Temp\android\res" -A "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Compiler\Temp\android\assets" -I "C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar" -F "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Compiler\Temp\android\bin\actividad.unsigned.apk" "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Compiler\Temp\android\bin" 

// SIGNS THE APK EXECUTABLE.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\jarsigner.exe
 ***IRRELEVANT, AND NOT POSTED BECAUSE OF KEYS***

//LIST THE DEVICES.
C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
 devices 

// GETS THE NAME OF THE PLUGGED DEVICE
C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
 -s 1c523b41 shell getprop ro.product.model 

// CLEARS THE LOGCAT.
C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
 logcat -c

// INSTALLS THE COMPILED APK.
C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
 -e -s 1c523b41 install -r C:\Users\brian\Documents\Compiler\Temp\android\bin\actividad.apk

// RUNS IT.
C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
 shell am start -n com.Actividad.Brian/.actividad 

// DISPLAYS THE LOGCAT AFTER THE CRASH.
C:\Users\brian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
 logcat
```

I think i am not including the Google play JAR correctly, but i dont see where the error resides....

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using emulator to run this app?

Comment: Yes, some times. Non-google-play applications work great in either a device or an emulator, but both crashes when invoking setContentView(). If your question is because of the -e switch, it works also with physical devices, according to the manual. In the example above, i installed the APK to my Sansung Galaxy.

Comment: Generally Fatal Exceptions comes when googlemaps are not installed on your device and you are not initiating the map before using it.Make sure GoogleMap and Play Services are installed on the device you are running the app

Comment: Both are installed. I am 99% certain this is a compile-time bug, as other apps use Google Maps normally.

Comment: Try removing google-play-services  from your project's reference and adding them back, delete bin folder from the project  and clean the project, build workspace again. Must work

Comment: If you want to stick to the command-line I would recommend switching to the build tool gradle. Once configured it makes command-line compiling, signing, installing,... a one liner.

Comment: Bhavik, My compiler doesnt have an option to do all that, it creates the whoel thing on every compile

Robert, I would like to avoid having to install yet another tool... Now i am only 1 step away from achieving what i need.

Comment: Some reason for not using Gradle wrapper?

Comment: Yes. Is the design the users like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I only needed to compile the resources separately. LIke this

```
// COMPILES THE LIBRARY CLASS.
 package -f -m --auto-add-overlay -S "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res" -J "C:\Users\Brian\Documents\output\Temp\android\src" -M "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\AndroidManifest.xml" -I "C:\Users\Brian\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-22\android.jar"
```

I didnt kow there where two separate processes, i thought both resources should be compiled by the same command line.